# "Psychological disposition of car ownership" - is that a term?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology, british-english

I am searching for a term to describe the following:
The psychological value that is attached to car ownership.

The context: 
I am doing a research towards carsharing and writing about factors that influence the decision to participate in a carsharing program or not. It is found that some people derive more status from car ownership than others do and now I would like to refer to this with a simple term, so I can actually make nice schemes and infographics without long sentences. It should be some kind of term that can become larger or smaller (like household size, environmental concern or PT accessibility).

For now I have come up with: 'Psychological disposition of car ownership'. Is that actually a term that works in English?

P.S. I am writing my thesis in British-English.

Comment: I am not sure you are using "disposition" correctly here. But you need to give us a full sentence, and ideally some context. Presumably you are referring to the extent to which people are "disposed" to own rather than share a car. What was wrong with "Psychological value of car ownership"?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. To give you a sentence: Furthermore, the psychological disposition of car ownership is found to play a role in the trade off between car ownership and carsharing membership.

In reaction to: 'Psychological value of car ownership'. To me this does not seem as a characteristic that changes per household, but correct me if I'm wrong. To turn it into a household characteristic, I should convert it into: "Psychological value that is attached to car ownership". But I want something cleaner and more simple like 'Environmental concern'.

Comment: I think if to are going to use the word "disposition" you need to follow it with the preposition "to". If you use "of" is changes the sense of "disposition" to something rather different. "The psychological disposition to car ownership is found to play a role...". I have a "disposition to do something". But "the disposition of the cavalry saved the day". "Disposition of" relates to positioning.